# understanding jQuery ready event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am trying to replace a div with some other content on click of a link using Ajax.
The content is getting replaced fine.

The problem area is that now i have to do operations on this new div content. All the code for operations  goes in (document).ready(function{});

The issue is that i am unable to run the code for mousedown event in the newly div content.
My page source shows the old dive content only.

Any help/pointers  will be appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: Try understanding delegated event handlers instead, and you're golden!

Comment: Document ready only pertains to the initial page load. Also, it couldn't hurt to put some code down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, nothing JavaScript does will be reflected in your source code, only in the DOM. The former is the physical code of your pages, as compiled on and sent by the server as a result of any server-side technologies that may be there, while the latter is the current state of that manipulated source code that the browser has parsed, reflecting any changes made by JavaScript.

As @adeneo said in his comment, you need to look into delegated events. True, this is not the only way around your problem, but it's sensible nonetheless and a good pattern in the long run with regard to events (especially where many elements are involved.)

The trick with delegated events is to bind not to the elements themselves but to a common parent. In jQuery, delegated events are handled by passing a filter selector rather than a callback as the second argument to `.on()` (with the callback bumped to the third argument). So:

```
$('body').on('mousedown', 'div.foo', function() {
     //callback code
});
```

That will fire on mousedown to **any** `div` with class 'foo', regardless of whether it's in the DOM to start with or injected later on. This would not be the case with a non-delegated event, like:

```
$('div.foo').on('mousedown', function() {
     //callback code
});
```

That would bind only to matching `div`s that were in the DOM at the time that code ran. It would not apply to any injected into the DOM later.

Answer (score 0):

Look into jQuery '.on'

```
$('#mydiv').on('click',function(){


}
```